# NodeJs scheduling jobs on multiple nodes

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have two nodeJs servers running behind a Load Balancer. I have some scheduled jobs that i want to run only once on any of the two instances in a distributed manner.

Which module should i use ? Will node-quartz(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-quartz) be useful for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Adding redis and using `node-redlock` seemed like overkill for the little caching job I needed to schedule for once a day on a single server with three Node.js processes behind a load balancer.

I discovered http://kvz.io/blog/2012/12/31/lock-your-cronjobs/ - and that led me to the concept behind Tim Kay's [`solo`](http://timkay.com/solo/).

The concept goes like this - instead of locking on an object (only works in a single process) or using a distributed lock (needed for multiple servers), "lock" by listening on a *port*. All the processes on the server share the same ports. And if the process fails, it will (of course) release the port.

Note that hard-failing (no catch anywhere surrounding) or releasing the lock in `catch` are both OK, but neglecting to release the lock when catching exceptions around the critical section will mean that the scheduled job never executes until the locking process gets recycled for some other reason.

I'll update when I've tried to implement this.

**Edit**

Here's my working example of locking on a port:

*multiProc.js*

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('error', function () { console.log('I am process number two!'); });

server.listen({ port: 3000 },
    function () { console.log('I am process number one!');
                  setTimeout(function () {server.close()}, 3000); });
```

If I run this twice within 3 seconds, here's the output from the first and second instances

*first*

> I am process number one!

*second*

> I am process number two!

If, on the other hand, more than 3 seconds pass between executing the two instances, both claim to be process number one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before but I can see myself doing it this way.

- Using any scheduler library for Node.js.
- In order to achieve your goal, i would use redis for distributed lock. Before running any scheduled jobs, a worker / node will have to get the lock; do the job; and release / ack() when finishing the job (or on error).

Comment: What happens when both try to get the lock at the same time ?

Comment: @VikasTiwari you can read more about redlock algorithm on redis.io http://redis.io/topics/distlock

Answer (score 0):

A single server can be selected a leader by conducting a election among available instances using Zoologist package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/zoologist

Requires Zookeeper server to conduct the election

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help you, but still posting it here.

Usually `node-schedule` is used for time based schedules where you have to execute arbitrary code only once. For eg: a database read/write on next month 6:00 PM.

Answer (score -3):

The following post will explain writing the scheduled Jobs which will perform certain action based on our requirement for a particular time / day instance.

For performing the above task we are going to use CRON package of node.
To add a job we need to :

1) Install Cron

```
npm install cron
```

2) Require cron 's CronJob to our project.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob
```

3) Create an instance of CronJob

```
var jobs = new CronJob({
cronTime: ' * * * * * *',
 onTick: function () {
      //perform Your action
 },
 start: false,
 timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
});
```

**Arguments**

**cronTime**: it takes 6 arguments namely :

1) Second - > 0 - 59

2) Minute - > 0 - 59

3) Hour - > 0 - 23

4) Day of Month - > 1 - 31

5) Months - > 0 - 11

6) Day of Week - > 0 - 6

**Note:** We Can define cronTime in ranges alse like * for always.
0 - 59 / 5 at every 5 minute.

**onTick:** The operation to perform.

**Start:** It takes a boolean and if true then starts the job now.

**timeZone:** job's timeZone

4) To start Job

```
jobs.start()
```

For Example :

```
var jobs = new CronJob({
        cronTime: ' 00 00 0-23 * * *',
        onTick: function () {
            printMyName();
        },
        start: false,
        timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
    });

   jobs.start();

 var printMyName = function () {
     var date = new Date();
    console.log("Hi Vipul  it is ", today);
 };
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to assert that only one node executes the cron task, which is the point of the question, not how to use the `cron` library.